# Context menus visually corrupted with static-like appearance (picture included)

Tags: gnome, xorg, gtk, lts, context-menu

Whenever I open a context menu in a few places, it is covered by corruption as shown in the picture:

[image: picture of corrupted context menu]

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, Gnome 3.36.8 and X11.
Started all of a sudden, is consistently reproducible, which means certain context menus or bookmark folder lists always are corrupted and others not.

Funny enough, if I manage to guess where the option is, I can click it and it works fine.

My CPU is a Ryzen 5 3400g.
I never had that issue before despite using this machine as it is for around three years now.

Comment: Do you have a Nvidia card installed? If so, what version driver?

Comment: Is this a laptop on battery with an Intel graphics card? If the latter, try adding the kernel parameter `i915.enable_psr=0` to `/etc/defaults/grub`.

Comment: Nope, I'm on a desktop with a ryzen 5 3400g cpu, no graphic cards, the cpu handles that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by disabling hardware acceleration in Chromium browser.